# Backup file is not visible in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I right click on a database, select Tasks and then Backup. For destination there is this destination :

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
```

When I click OK, it says

> The backup of database 'mydb' completed successfully

But when I navigate to that folder written above, folder looks empty. Why is it empty? Why can't I see the backup files? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There is steps you should follow to backup a BD in SQL Server.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

Comment: The file is created on the **server** not your local computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup file exist on the path you entered but on the same server that has the database. So, unless you are running the SQL Server instance on your local machine, you should remotely connect to the server that hosts SQL Server and copy the backup from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was struggling for several days trying many things but nothing helped. Somehow, I finally found the solution which turned out to be quite easy.
So,
1st, you need to create a folder in you (C:) Drive, create just one empty folder.
Then when you are making back up in SQL, REMOVE previous location, and click ADD button. and there you choose the folder you created in (C:), choose it and then fill the "file name" gap. there you should write new name, not the database name, just create some random name. you should add: .bak  when you write the name.
Save the name,  and click OK. that's it.
back up is successful!

Answer (score 0):

Verify your back up path is correct or not as you chosen and also give file name with extension `.bak`

Refer to this URL : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pPcX8gvT9g

Answer (score 0):

**Backing up a complete database:**

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDB   
 TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Your_Backup.bak'  
   WITH FORMAT;  
GO
```

**Note:** Create a logical backup device.

Answer (score 0):

Try With backup using query and specify path.

```
        BACKUP DATABASE [YourDB] TO  DISK = N'SomePath\YourDB.bak' 
        WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'YourDB Full Database Backup', 
        SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
        GO
```